# How to get content from another page?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to using the .get() method but is my first time hehe. What I need to do to make it work?

```
const quickSilverBtn = $('#QS-btn');

    quickSilverBtn.on('click', function() {
    const lookbookWrapper = $('.lookbook-content-wrapper');

       $.get( "http://kokomo-a76bf4.webflow.io/brands/quicksilver/man", function( data ) {
          $( "#man-qsilver-content" ).html( data );
          console.log( $("#man-qsilver-content") );
       });

       lookbookWrapper.append('#man-qsilver-content');

    });
```

I want to grab the content from another page and put it on a div. What I need to do? 
I'm very frustrated hehe
Thanks a lot people!

Comment: I imagine you're running into the same origin policy, and that your browser's debugging console is indicating this.  If it isn't, then in what way *is* this failing?

Comment: Reading about a `HTTP 405` will help you to u derstand about this

Comment: Look in the JS console. Any messages in there like `Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.` Are you running this code from a local file, eg `file://`? If so, check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)

Comment: ok. I just make it work. But, now in Safari the images wont load. Why?